# capturar con que botón del mouse se hizo click sobre la ventana mediante con switch case JS

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de capturar el botón del mouse con el que se hace click sobre la ventana, ahora usé un switch case, sin embargo solo captura el case 0, cuando le hago click a los demas botones no pasa nada, nisiquiera el default funciona, que  podría hacer en este caso?

Gracias por la ayuda.

```js
window.addEventListener("click", check_button);

function check_button(e){
    switch(e.button) {
        case 0:
            console.log("Presionó el botón izquierdo");
            break;
        case 1:
            console.log("Presionó el botón medio");
            break;
        case 2:
            console.log("Presionó el botón derecho");
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Presionó otro botón"); 
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo con [Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button) tenemos a nuestra disposición un evento llamado:

**mouseup**

El cual nos servirá para:

> The MouseEvent.button read-only property indicates which button was pressed on the mouse to trigger the event.

Que podemos traducir como:

> Propiedad de solo lectura para indicar que botón del mouse fue presionado y en consecuencia disparó el evento

Dicho lo anterior tu código queda funcional con ese cambio:

```
window.addEventListener("mouseup", check_button);
```

El evento `click` no te sirve para lo que buscas pues esta destinado solo a hacer saber si se hizo click sobre [algún elemento](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event)

Puedes tu mismo colocar la función de esta forma:

```
function check_button(e){
      console.log(e.button)
}
```

Y te estará devolviendo los siguiente valores:

- 0 Botón izquierdo
- 1 Botón central (la ruedita de desplazamiento)
- 2 Botón derecho